# Workstation trust relationship missing on domain member PC

Tags: windows-vista, security, domain

I have a PC that my colleague tried to switch from domain membership back to workgroup a short while ago.  I corrected most of the ensuing chaos with a system restore, but now although the PC seems to think it belongs to the domain, when I try and log on with a domain account, I get the message:

```
"server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship".
```

I'm guessing that on leaving the domain, some account was removed from the domain server.  What can I do to correct this?

Comment: The account is probably there they're just out of sync...looking around a bit for the reset computer account howto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the computer account is actually in AD look for its DN, next you can try

```
dsmod computer ComputerDN -reset
```

more discussion of dsmod for resets is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778276%28WS.10%29.aspx

if you use groups to manage policy and don't have a lot of policy directly on that PC, you could just delete the computer account and rejoin it to the domain manually - **not recommended if you don't know what how corporate wide policies are applied**

Comment: I've just reset the computer using the console on AD, and yet I still get the same error.

Comment: hmph...there's a way to force something similar to a new add, i can't remember at the moment...it's in the mcitp ent admin server study guides.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the computer was disabled in AD.  I now get an incorrect password error despite resetting the password twice, but that's another question.